# pgAdmin 4 version 3 fails to open a second time

Tags: pgadmin, mac-os-x, pgadmin-4

I just installed [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org) version 3.0.0 for [macOS Sierra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Sierra), replacing the [pgAdmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL#pgAdmin) that came bundled with [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) 10.3 running locally on the same Mac.

I opened the `pgAdmin 4.app` app icon, which caused [Safari browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_(web_browser)) to come to the front with a tab showing the usual pgAdmin user-interface. Good.

I closed that tab in Safari. Now when I open the `pgAdmin 4.app` icon (either double-clicking or choosing `File` > `Open`), nothing happens.

Is pgAdmin supposed to launch in a browser window rather than in the app's own window?

➡ How to re-open pgAdmin again?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

## “Elephant” icon menu

When pgAdmin is running, an elephant icon menu appears. Look at the upper right corner of the screen. The elephant refers to [*Slonik*](http://www.vertabelo.com/blog/notes-from-the-lab/the-history-of-slonik-the-postgresql-elephant-logo), the Postgres mascot.

Choose `New pgAdmin Window` menu item.

[image]

FYI, pgAdmin 4 is built as a web app, not a desktop app, even when run locally on your own computer. Note that the internal web server provided by pgAdmin 4 is running continuously, even after you close all windows. Use the `Shutdown server` menu item, as seen above, if you want to stop that web server.

p.s. I agree, it is very confusing that clicking the icon does not do the same thing (when pgAdmin is already running).

Comment: Bingo! I found such a menu with pgAdmin 4 version 3.0. The menu item works. Thank you.

Comment: It's the elephant in the room... that nobody sees.

Comment: I see pgadmin in the Activity Monitor, but no elephant in the top bar

Answer (score 8):

**Update** For best solution, see [Answer by Burmistrov](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/212026/19079).

## Web browser

As for launching the app causing a page to open in your default web browser, Yes, that is the new normal.

Per an email on the psgsql-announce email sent by Dave Page on 2018-04-13:

> The desktop runtime now runs as a system tray application and utilises the browser on the system to display pgAdmin. This resolves numerous bugs and issues caused by QtWebKit/QtWebEngine.

## Second launching

As for the app doing nothing when launching after closing the first web browser window, one workaround: Bookmark the URL.

Here is an example of such a URL:

> http://127.0.0.1:58353/browser/

The port number, 58353 in the example above, varies arbitrarily. To discover the port in use currently, do a [port-scan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner).

## Kill the pgAdmin server process

The **pgAdmin 4 app is actually architected as a web app running inside a bundled web server**. So the port number listed above is the port on which that bundled web server is listening.

So one workaround to our re-open-app problem is to kill the process of the web server of pgAdmin. Then run the pgAdmin 4 app again to re-launch the bundled web server, re-create the `pgAdmin 4` process, and have your default web browser open a fresh window.

[image: screenshot of Mac app Activity Monitor offering to kill the 'pgAdmin 4' process]

## Alternate tool

Yes, pgAdmin 4 is annoying in this regard and in other regards as well. You may want to pursue using alternate admin tools. There are many to choose.

Comment: RE: second launching The only/fastest way I found to get a second launching (short of rebooting) was to terminate the pgAdmin 4 process in Activity Monitor. Then relaunch worked fine, but needed to do this for every relaunch. Bookmarking the URL did not help - it gave an error.

Comment: excellent question with a nice, clarifying answer.

Comment: the port 58353 is randomly change. You cannot bookmark

Comment: @BrianF Thanks, killing the `pgAdmin 4` process is a simple workaround. I added that to my Answer.

Answer (score 3):

After installing pgadmin4-3.0, I removed it and reinstalled pgadmin4-2.1.  The issues that this new version resolves are outweighed by the challenges it also introduces, in my view. After reverting to 4-2.1, I received the message "application server could not be contacted" when opening pgAdmin.  To resolve this issue, I renamed ~/.pgadmin, but this resulted in losing my saved connections.