# Open pgAdmin4 server on a Mac

Tags: pgadmin, mac-os-x

I had pgAdmin4-3.6 installed on my Mac. Worked as it should. And there was created a shortcut at installation to open the pgAdmin server.

Installing version pgAdmin4-4.6 there was no shortcut created to start the pgAdmin4 server. The old shortcut opens the old pgAdmin4.

```
open -a pgAdmin\ 4
```

also opens the old pgAdmin4-3.6

http://127.0.0.1:49206/browser/# and the "elephant meny" only works if the server is started. It starts when reinstalling from the dmg package.

How do I create a shortcut to start the new pgAdmin4-4.6 server on a Mac? 
Or redirect the old pgAdmin4.app to the new pgAdmin4-4.6?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have different browser processes running? I haven't tested this but try to close all the open browser windows. pgAdmin could cause some troubles regarding to system default browser https://stackoverflow.com/a/51780450/6618610

Did you try to restart the pgadmin service ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45519198/6618610

Restarting postgres would be even better.

I had an issue with pgAdmin4 so I restarted everything. That didn't go through seamlessly neither:

```
~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 1238)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/12.1/bin/postgres "-D" "/usr/local/var/postgres"
~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres restart
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop   
waiting for server to shut down............................................................... failed
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

I had a brew install so I used:

```
~ % brew services stop postgresql
```

After that I used pg_ctl to have the control over auto-start:

```
~ % pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

<sup>*See the comments section [https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251522/6618610](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24251522/6618610_)*</sup>

Or another approach, certainly better than killing processes:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56611776/6618610

Your postgres service should be back running. Now retry again to start pgAdmin from the launchpad. Don't forget to check on **Slonik**, because it might appear up there and you won't even know : )

[image: Slonik]

Copy the server URL from there or get it in the pgAdmin address file located in home folder. Type

```
~ % cat .pgAdmin4.###.addr
```

> *### a random numeric value* use <kbd>TAB</kbd> for `autocomplete`

Now start your favourite browser and paste the link in the bar.

<sub>*Also read those references:

[pgAdmin 4 version 3 fails to open a second time](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203981/pgadmin-4-version-3-fails-to-open-a-second-time)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671327/correct-way-to-start-stop-postgres-database-pg-ctl-or-service-postgres

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x#23628638](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7975556/how-to-start-postgresql-server-on-mac-os-x#23628638_)*</sub>